# java.reflection.Method.invoke(...) Not re-casting args

Tags: java, swing, reflection

I am trying out Java Reflection API. I am just fetching the Method objects of any given class into a JComboBox, and on it's itemSelected, creating an interface for the parameters (and of course, a calling object.)

This works fine, no issued.

But on the invokeButton's action, I am trying to invke the selected method with given params.

Initially it said that the param count differed. I was guided by one of my friend saying that the paramVals array has references to actual values, which might be causing problem, may be due to scope. I then started creating new objects of class Object and then assigning them the values. This worked for param count. But now the problem is that the parameters are not type cast properly. Even a String typecast to Object (as it has to be an array of Objects) is not being cast back to String.

The doc says that the invoke method will cast them on it's own and if cast fails, will throw an IllegalArgumentException.

I am not getting what is causing the call of invoke method fails...

Here is the code for the frame:

```
package nttraining.abhay.reflectiondemo;
//imports go here

public class ReflectionFrame 
    extends JFrame
    implements ActionListener, ItemListener{

    JComboBox methods;
    JButton invokeButton;

    public ReflectionFrame(String title) throws HeadlessException {
        super(title);
        //Layout components

        //adding methods of class String to a combo
        Class<String> c = String.class;
        Method ml[] = c.getMethods();
        for(Method m : ml){
            methods.addItem(m);
        }

        invokeButton.addActionListener(this);
        methods.addItemListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource().equals(invokeButton)){
            Method selected = (Method) methods.getSelectedItem();
            Class paramtypes[] = selected.getParameterTypes();
            Object paramVals[] = new Object[paramtypes.length];
            System.out.println("Method : " + selected.toString());
            for(int i=0; i<paramtypes.length; i++){
                Object obj = new Object();
                obj = paramtypes[i].cast(params[i].getText());
                paramVals[i] = obj;
                System.out.println("Added " + paramtypes[i].cast(params[i].getText()).toString() + " to params");
            }
            try {
                result.setText(selected.invoke(object.getText(), params).toString());

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getClass().getName() + ": " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        Method selected = (Method) methods.getSelectedItem();
        if(selected==null)
            return;
        Class paramtypes[] = selected.getParameterTypes();
        int paramCount = paramtypes.length;
        object = new JTextField();
        paramNames = new JLabel[paramCount];
        params = new JTextField[paramCount];
        panel.removeAll();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(paramCount+1, 2));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Calling object"));
        panel.add(object);
        for(int i=0; i<paramCount; i++){
            paramNames[i] = (JLabel) panel.add(new JLabel(paramtypes[i].getName()));
            params[i] = (JTextField) panel.add(new JTextField());
        }
        invalidate();
        validate();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My code is not being displayed fully... What shall I do for it now? :(

Comment: You've some more code to show? It would be better if you can put just the relevant part.

Answer (score 0):

A problem I found is in this line:

`obj = paramtypes[i].cast(params[i].getText());`

`cast` does not convert objects, it only verfies that the given object is of a certain class. Since you always provide a `String.class` as parameter (via `.getText()`), this will fail for anything other then a String type parameter. Even Integer.class to primitive int will fail.

Below a piece of code that demonstrates the `cast` problem.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Q21642768 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        // Calls String.indexOf(str, fromIndex) via reflection.
        callStringMethod("Hello reflection world", "reflection", 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void callStringMethod(String s, String subString, int startIndex) throws Exception {

    Class<String> c = String.class;
    Method ma[] = c.getMethods();
    Method indexOfSub = null;
    Class<?>[] indexOfSubPTypes = null;
    List<Method> stringMethods = new ArrayList<Method>();
    List<Type[]> stringMethodsPTypes = new ArrayList<Type[]>();
    for (Method m: ma) {
        stringMethods.add(m);
        System.out.print(m.getName() + ": ");
        Class<?>[] mptypes = m.getParameterTypes();
        stringMethodsPTypes.add(mptypes);
        boolean first = true;
        for (Type t : mptypes) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
            System.out.print(t.toString());
        }
        if ("indexOf".equals(m.getName()) 
                && mptypes.length == 2 
                && mptypes[0].equals(String.class)
                && mptypes[1].equals(int.class)) {
            indexOfSub = m;
            indexOfSubPTypes = mptypes;
            System.out.println(" <-- ");
        } else {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    if (indexOfSub == null) {
        System.out.println("target method not found");
        return;
    }
    Object[] pValues = new Object[2];
    pValues[0] = indexOfSubPTypes[0].cast(subString);
    // Fails:
    // pValues[1] = indexOfSubPTypes[1].cast(startIndex);
    // pValues[1] = indexOfSubPTypes[1].cast(startIndex + "");
    pValues[1] = startIndex;

    Object result = indexOfSub.invoke(s, pValues);
    System.out.println("Result: " + result);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all your parameter values are String objects, since you get them with JTextField.getText(). String is the runtime type of these values, whereas the type of the method parameters will generally be different, and this is what matters.

To successfully invoke the method, you will first need to convert each value to the proper type specified in the paramTypes array. Neither cast() nor invoke() are going to do that for you. This means you must find a way to do the conversion from a String, basically deserializing from a String value into an object of the proper class, and that may not always be possible or too complex to do. At this point, I think you can start to imagine the complexity of what you are trying to do. This is very far from trivial. Remember that each parameter value will generally not be a simple value, but rather a full object graph, that's where the complexity is.

For example, if the type of a method parameter is an interface, how will you know which concrete implementation to instantiate? If you do find a concrete class implementing it - and that may not always be possible - how will you create instances of that class? Here you're entering a domain covered by serialization frameworks in Java. There are quite a few of these frameworks that are open source and you might want to take a look at some of them. You will find a comprenhesive list of such fraleworks [here](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki).

A few years ago, I worked on a related project, where I had to provide a Swing GUI to enable end-users to create objects of arbitrary types, used as input for a rule engine. What I came up with was a JTree with multiple roots, associated with a property sheet (i.e. a JTable with 2 columns), where the tree leaves were either simple types (primitives, primitive wrappers, Date, etc.) or object references. Each reference would point to a specific tree root representing the actual object to be later instantiated. I don't remember exactly how long it took, just that it took several months to get it tested and working.

So, I don't want to crush your hopes, but you should be aware that it's going to take a huge amount of work to do this.

Comment: Thanks, @Lolo, for your valuable input. I do understand that it will be quiet a pain to pass an argument of an arbitrary type (say, an awt component) with string is definitely tough, and I don't plan to do that either.

I just wanted to see how reflection can be used... And here if all the params are string, still it isn't working. That is what troubling me most. Not a single method is being invoked successfully, even those with no args, as simple as String.length() too!

What is missing here, do you think? Can you help me further?

Comment: And as I thought further on what you said, I am in front of a recurring issue... Suppose we use some standard like XML to describe an object with all it's properties, so that they are passed properly to methods being called via Reflection, and then we write a class that creates actual object, again we shall see, in xml, that "Text" property is set to "ABC" and hence we will need to call "setText()" function again via Reflection!!

How to break this cycle?

Comment: Maybe it would help if you could describe the error you get when invoking String.length() via reflection, exception + stack trace would really be useful

Comment: I don't understand why you'd need to call setText() via reflection. The XML stuff could be done with the XStream serialization framework, it will allow you to convert XML into actual Java objects via deserialization, and vice-versa